# C# List - Sorting Data

Tags: c#

I am trying to add elements into a list, order them and then output them, there a number of "columns" if you like, per list

```
List<Info> infoList = new List<Info>();

while (dr.Read())
{

   meeting_id = dr.GetValue(0).ToString();
   try
   {
      Appointment appointment = Appointment.Bind(service, new ItemId(meeting_id));

      Info data = new Info();
      data.Start = appointment.Start;
      data.Fruit = Convert.ToInt32(dr.GetValue(1));
      data.Nuts = Convert.ToInt32(dr.GetValue(2));

      infoList.Add(data);

   }
```

Then to output it I want to order it by Start and then display all associated columns

```
 for (int i = 0; i < infoList.Count; i++)
 {
     meet = meet + infoList[i];
 }
```

First question: is the way I am inputting the data right?

Second question: How to I output all the columns to display all the associated columns? Is this possible? Is there a better practice?

Thanks

EDIT:

The class if you are interested:

```
public class Info
{
    public DateTime Start { get; set; }
    public int Fruit { get; set; }
    public int Nuts { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use [Enumerable.OrderBy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534966%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) extension for enumerating your collection in some particular order (e.g. ordered by `Start` property value):

```
foreach(var info in infoList.OrderBy(i => i.Start))
{
    // use info object here
    // info.Fruits
    // info.Nuts
}
```

BTW consider to add sorting on database side - that will be more efficient

Comment: Thanks, the reason I can't sort database side is that no start date is pulled from the database. The only thing stored in the database is the meeting ID (from Outlook), the "fruit" and the "nuts" and then I use EWS to pull in the start time from Exchange.

Comment: @CorbinSpicer I see. Then you have only option to sort collection in memory